# Java editor doesn't know anything about primefaces

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces

I am trying code something in PrimeFaces...I have been already succesfull with JSF (anotations and calling java variables in .xhtml file). Now I would like to code something with PrimeFaces framework, but my Eclipse does not know anything about primefaces classes. When I want to create variable of the type DefaultDiagramModel, it just tell me, that DefaultDiagramModel cnanot be resolved to a type. I have primefaces in my POM file and you can also see the library in my lib folder. Thanks for help!

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iII07.jpg)

Comment: You mean, when you put the cursor after `DefaultDiagramModel` word and press Ctrl+Space, then you don't see the correct import in the autocomplete list? In other words, the desired class is absent in the build path? Does the same really happen for all other PrimeFaces classes? (namely, screenshot suggests a different cause)

Comment: Solved. I am sorry for my own stupidity. Primefaces 5.0 doesn't have DefaultDoagramModel type. I just downloaded 5.2 version and everything si fine.

Comment: As I guessed, "anything" was thus a careless assumption. In the future don't do that. You'll automatically stop by yourself thinking twice.